# .NET Regex pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

```
var flashvars = {
        "client.allow.cross.domain" : "0", 
        "client.notify.cross.domain" : "1",
};
```

For some strange reason *does not* want to be parsed with this code (in C#).

```
private void parseVariables() {
       String page;
       Regex flashVars = new Regex("var flashvars = {(.*?)}", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
       Regex var = new Regex(@"""(.*?)"",", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
       Match flashVarsMatch;
       MatchCollection matches;
       String vars = "";

       if (!IsLoggedIn)
       {
            throw new NotLoggedInException();
       }

       page = Request(URL_CLIENT);

       flashVarsMatch = flashVars.Match(page);

       matches = var.Matches(flashVarsMatch.Groups[1].Value);

       if (matches.Count > 0)
       {
         foreach (Match item in matches)
         {
            vars += item.Groups[1].Value.Replace("\" : \"", "=") + "&";
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Scott: just to be pedantic: C# is a programming language which has no regex support at all (unlike JavaScript). OTOH, the .NET Framework has the System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `RegexOptions.SingleLine` rather than `RegexOptions.Multiline`

**RegexOptions.Singleline**

> Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except\n).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/443e8hc7(vs.71).aspx

Comment: Problem fixed. Thanks vfilby and Max Shawabkeh.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `Singleline` flag. Otherwise a period doesn't match new lines. `MultiLine` is used to make `^` and `$` match at start/end of lines. Also, you need to escape the curly brackets:

```
Regex flashVars = new Regex(@"var flashvars = \{(.*?)\}", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I cannot seem to find the DotAll flag, are you sure it's a valid RegexOption for C# .NET?

Comment: DotAll is known as single line, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740176/net-regex-pattern/2740273#2740273.

Comment: Fixed. Used to Python's naming. The .NET equivalent is `Singleline`.

Comment: You have to escape the backslash for the c# string with another one, so it should be `"var flashvars = \\{(.*?)\\}"`

Comment: @Philip Daubmeier: Made the string raw.